# PHP Group By Array of Object using 2 Keys

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I have to modify the original data into a new set of data using PHP, The original from query would return like :

```
Result                                   Expected Result :
[                                        [
 {                                        {
  'PRODUCT' : 'BANANA',                    'PRODUCT' : 'BANANA',
  'BUY_PERIOD' : '202101',                 'BUY_PERIOD' : '202101',
  'SALES_PERIOD' : '202101',               'SALES_PERIOD' : [ 
  'PERCENT_OF_SALES' : "20",                                 {
 },                                                            '202101' : "20",
 {                                                             '202102' : "10",
  'PRODUCT' : 'BANANA',                                        '202103' : "15",
  'BUY_PERIOD' : '202101',                                     '202104' : "35"
  'SALES_PERIOD' : '202102',                                 }
  'PERCENT_OF_SALES' : "10",                                ]
 },                                       }
 {                                       ]
  'PRODUCT' : 'BANANA',
  'BUY_PERIOD' : '202101',
  'SALES_PERIOD' : '202103',
  'PERCENT_OF_SALES' : "15",
 },
 {
  'PRODUCT' : 'BANANA',
  'BUY_PERIOD' : '202101',
  'SALES_PERIOD' : '202104',
  'PERCENT_OF_SALES' : "35",
 },
]
```

I need the expected result to make something like :
[image]

On my previous question, i already asked the similiar question, using JavaScript ES6.Here is the the link to my previous question [JSON Multidimensional Array to HTML Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68094988/json-multidimensional-array-to-html-table) 
This time, i had to do it using PHP (Laravel)
Any kind of help will be really appriciated , Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP JSON Array - Group by the same value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27327881/php-json-array-group-by-the-same-value/46544028) or [PHP JSON Group by the same value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30815807/php-json-group-by-the-same-value)

Comment: @DefinitelynotRafal i have tried the first code earlier, the second code almost work, but still working on modifying it. the result still not as expected

Comment: Then you should be able to show us what you tried, which are you expected to do. That way we can improve on your attempt and help you understand what went wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [array_reduce](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) function as approach:

```
$result = array_reduce(
    $data,
    function($res, $el) {
        if (isset($res[$el['PRODUCT'] . "-" . $el['BUY_PERIOD']])) {
            $res[$el['PRODUCT'] . "-" . $el['BUY_PERIOD']]['SALES_PERIOD'][$el['SALES_PERIOD']] = $el['PERCENT_OF_SALES'];
        } else {
            $res[$el['PRODUCT'] . "-" . $el['BUY_PERIOD']] = [
                'PRODUCT' => $el['PRODUCT'],
                'BUY_PERIOD' => $el['BUY_PERIOD'],
                'SALES_PERIOD' => [
                    $el['SALES_PERIOD'] => $el['PERCENT_OF_SALES']
                ]
            ];
        }
        
        return $res;
    },
    
    $res
);
```

[PHP execute online](https://phpize.online/?phpses=177e8636b8c1f1dbae6945fae4fbc3cf&sqlses=null&php_version=php8&sql_version=mysql57)

Comment: This works well, but if i add more buy_period data , for example 202102 , the new buy period didn't show up

Comment: Here I added new buy period. It looks ok: https://phpize.online/?phpses=1169571ddd4cd03464e66a0d4ae75f93&sqlses=null&php_version=php8&sql_version=mysql57

Comment: thank you sir, this allows me to continue to make a pivot table using new dataset

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't return the data exactly in the format you require, but gives you the same nested structure using two keys as the question specifies. Use `PRODUCT` as the first key in the array, then `SALES_PERIOD` as a second key. Add each row to the nested array through your `foreach`

```
foreach($result as $row){
    $return[$row['PRODUCT']]['PRODUCT'] = $result['PRODUCT'];
    $return[$row['PRODUCT']]['BUY_PERIOD'] = $result['BUY_PERIOD'];
    $return[$row['PRODUCT']]['SALES_PERIOD'][$result['SALES_PERIOD']] = $result['PERCENT_OF_SALES'];
}

json_encode($return);
```